# Solr Cloud Configuration

Tags: configuration, solrcloud

We only have two servers available for Solr, so we are considering the following config:
Server 1: Solr, Zookeeper
Server 2: Solr, Zookeeper
Server 3: Zookeeper, application X

I know that Zookeeper requires 3 nodes for a quorum but am not sure what the affect would be of having Solr running on only two of the nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Solr can run in cloud mode with only one node.

However, the advantage of using Solrcloud is to distribute the requests among the shards of your cluster. Simply put, the more replicas, the better loadbalancing and "read" performances. Having multiple instances insures better fault tolerance and failover.

Please have a look at the [Solr wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/How+SolrCloud+Works), or be more specific if you have other questions.